# How do Media Query so landscape view is applied only on tablet, not phone?

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

I don't want landscape view to appear when a phone is rotated to landscape, only a tablet-sized device. I'm using `em`'s for measurement but it's hard to pick a good cutoff. The Nexus 4 (for example) is `61.5em` wide in landscape (an iPad is `1024` or `64 em`) which is very wide but landscape view looks poor on that phone. Is there a good solution?

Comment: This is related to the screen size of the device, not Android or iOS (tags).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to setup device specifics for each device resolution. I'm not aware of any specifics that determine if you are looking at one specific device. Some phones are much easier to detect (like iPhone 6+) since they have specific abnormal resolutions. I know the @media handheld is ignored on many devices so that doesn't help much but give it a shot.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

You can add an orientation for a deeper test as well. Something like

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape)
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media